How to create an infinite scroll with smooth transitions (React)
Relevant code:
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useGames } from "../providers/gamesProvider";
import Card from "./Card";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const StyledScroller = styled.div`
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  gap: 16px;
  position: relative;

  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white, transparent); */

  &:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      to left,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
      rgba(15, 23, 42, 1) 90%
    );
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
      rgba(15, 23, 42, 1) 90%
    );
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
  }
`;

function Scroller() {
  const { activeIndex, setActiveIndex, gamesData } = useGames();
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);

  // Effect to handle the automatic looping of the activeIndex
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPaused) return; // If paused, don't start the interval

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setActiveIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % gamesData.length);
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [gamesData.length, setActiveIndex, isPaused]);

  // Calculate the previous and next indices based on the activeIndex
  const prevIndex = (activeIndex - 1 + gamesData.length) % gamesData.length;
  const nextIndex = (activeIndex + 1) % gamesData.length;


  // pause scroll functions
  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsPaused(true);
  };
  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsPaused(false);
  };

  const handleIncrementIndex = () => {
    setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
  };
  const handleDecrementIndex = () => {
    setActiveIndex(prevIndex);
  };

  return (
    <StyledScroller>
      <Card
        index={prevIndex}
        gamesData={gamesData}
        smol={true}
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
        onClick={handleDecrementIndex}
      />
      <Card
        index={activeIndex}
        gamesData={gamesData}
        smol={false}
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      />
      <Card
        index={nextIndex}
        gamesData={gamesData}
        smol={true}
        right={true}
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
        onClick={handleIncrementIndex}
      />
    </StyledScroller>
  );
}

export default Scroller;

import styled from "styled-components";
import GameLogo from "./GameLogo";
import Arrow from "./Arrow";

const StyledCard = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: ${(props) => (props.$smol ? "90%" : "100%")};
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;

  img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  }

  ${(props) =>
    !props.$smol &&
    `
    img:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }

     &:hover p {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  `}

  &::after {
    content: "";
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  &:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  p {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    animation: wobble infinite ease-in-out 2s;
    background-color: rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.5);
    padding: 6px 0;
  }

  p :not(span) {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  p span {
    display: inline;
  }

  @keyframes wobble {
    0% {
      transform: scale(1) translateY(-50%);
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-50%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1) translateY(-50%);
    }
  }
`;

function Card({ index, gamesData, smol, right, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, onClick }) {
  const href = gamesData[index].href;

  return (
    <StyledCard
      $smol={smol}
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <a href={href} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
        <img src={gamesData[index].screenshot} alt={`Game ${index + 1}`} />
        <p>Play {<GameLogo />} now!</p>
      </a>
      {smol && <Arrow right={right} />}
    </StyledCard>
  );
}

export default Card;

The view features 3 cards, one 'main' in the center, and two partially visible ones on both sides, slightly smaller as a visual indicator.
The user is able to cycle through the cards in either directions.
gameData contains data for 4 different cards.
What I'm trying to achieve is a smooth transition, which would translate the contents of Scroller right/left, and adjust the sizes of cards to indicate the 'main' one.
Currently the code will instantly transition to a new state.
Since the user can cycle in either direction, and I want to achieve a smooth transition, the 2 cards before and after should be rendered before they are visible to the end user. What I've tried is to generate an array after each Scroller re-render, which would indicate the currently rendered cards.
So, if the activeIndex = 0, array = [2,3,0,1,2], if it's 2, array = [0,1,2,3,0]. Ideally I want to update the array after the transition is done.
This approach has 2 problems:
If I set key to the map's index, the cards are 'new' each re-render and there can be no smooth transitions.
If I set key to the index of the data array, I have 2 duplicates.
Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/  you can use to animate element on scroll
